# Efficiently sort by a column whose sort order almost matches primary key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, sorting

We have a table of events in PostgreSQL 14 that looks like this

`event (event_id integer primary key, event_time integer, ... other columns)`

`event_id` is automatically set from a PG sequence, so it reflects the order in which events are inserted, which is very close to `event_time` order. This table can have hundreds of millions of rows and our application wants to read them ordered by `event_time`. Adding `order by event_time` is, of course, very slow without an index on that column. I don't really want to add an index, because it slows down inserts and takes more space.

Instead of that, we exploit the fact that events are inserted in batches and *almost* in order of `event_time`, e.g. the table may look something like this:

| event_id | event_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50000 |
| 2 | 50001 |
| 3 | 50005 |
| 4 | 50004 |
| 5 | 50005 |
| 6 | 50007 |

So we select with `order by event_id` (which is fast due to the PK) and then in the application code keep a buffer of the last *N* events read and re-arrange them into sorted order as we read. (We assume that an event will not be out of its sorted-by-event_time order by more than *N* places when sorted by `event_id`.) This works, but the code to do it is quite complex, so I just wonder if there is some simpler way to achieve the same result in Postgres, also exploiting the fact that PK order is almost the order we want?

Comment: You should try a BRIN index on `(event_time)`. They use extremely small space and are very efficient when the data are aligned as you describe. I assume the application does not read all the hundreds of millions of rows but uses some range (e.g. event_time >= 'yesterday').

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! On startup the application actually does read the entire table, but may later read small ranges of events, too.

Comment: Tried creating a BRIN index, but PG does not use it. EXPLAIN (and EXPLAIN ANAZLYE) output shows it's still doing a Seq Scan, Sort and Gather Merge, same as without the index. :( If I create a BTREE index it gets used.

Comment: I would expect to be used when selecting a small range. If you want to get back a large part of the table, it makes sense to do a full scan.

Comment: Yes, of course PG needs to scan the entire table when I'm requesting all rows, but it's a shame it can't use the BRIN index to do the sorting.

Comment: I found a [PG mailing list thread from 2016](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABoC1%3D69eJsWAgVz%2BErfLmnorpqjw2ac%2BX59xjKcZ9gXMotdzA%40mail.gmail.com) about this. It sounds like this could be implemented, but hasn't been so far.

Comment: Yes, reading that. TOP-n using BRIN index, that is the suggestion from what I understand and no, no one has worked on it yet. But it would be unlikely to be used for sorting a whole table.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do have a small range query (eg. `WHERE event_time >= '2022-09-01 17:00:00' AND event_time < '2022-09-01 18:00:00'`) I would expect the BRIN index to be used and assuming the number of rows is small, the sorting time to be negligible.

Comment: OK then, sounds like BRIN indexes don't help the main use case I want to optimize (reading the whole table ordered by event_time).